# Parsing phone number from EditText to Button

Tags: android, eclipse, button

I already know the code for calling a phone number using a button and edittext, but I don't know how to go on.

```
public void onClick(View arg0) {

    EditText num=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    String number = "tel:" +num.getText().toString().trim();
    Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL, Uri.parse(number));
    startActivity(callIntent);
}
```

I need the code that will allow a button labeled Button1 to parse this Intent.

Comment: Learning your android fundamentals would help you solve this.

Answer (score 1):

```
Button Button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1_id);
Button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
         public void onClick(View v) {
             // Perform action on click
             EditText num=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
             String number = "tel:" +num.getText().toString().trim();
             Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL, Uri.parse(number));
             startActivity(callIntent);
         }
     });
```